# context.Database.EnsureDeleted() and context.Database.EnsureCreated() fails

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing, entity-framework-core

I try to reproduce this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/sharing-databases),
it's about testing EF context operations in unit tests (using MS SQL Server).
This example contains next code:

```cs
using (var context = CreateContext())
{
   context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
   context.Database.EnsureCreated();
...
```

And it looks ok but ended up with exception:

> Cannot open database "EFTestSample" requested by the login. The login failed.

It is very confusing cause `EnsureDeleted()` should not open any database, it just checks persistence of this one. I'm totally sure it is not security issue, I have tried different cases of login.
UPD: EnsureDeleted() works fine (deletes database) when database exists on server.

Any help appreciated, thank.

Comment: Can you precise the provider used?

Comment: It's just a generic message that the connection can't be established. Try to connect from the same location with Management Studio to check if you can connect to the db server al all.

Comment: @vernou MS SQL Server. I've edited the question.

Comment: @GertArnold I've also updated answer with describing succesful case for EnsureDeleted(). I'm afraid this is really not security issue.

Comment: The it's probably something in the context itself (constructor, OnModelCreating, ...) that tries to connect.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: The SQL Server provider check if the database exists by logging in and running the query [SELECT 1](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/4722fe3f036fea11dbb1512fe8c2e84301cabc4c/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Storage/Internal/SqlServerDatabaseCreator.cs#L210)

Comment: @vernou meh... it's behaviour is rather different with declared for EnsureDeleted():
...returns true if the database is deleted, false if it did not exist.
No exceptions described in the docs.

Comment: I assume it's the best to check the existence with limited right. But this don't explain your problem.

Comment: As asked: show the stack trace. I bet `EnsureDeleted` is not the cause of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer. It was wrong namespace automatically detected for sample code from [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/sharing-databases). There are two classes implementing `System.Data.Common.DbConnection`:

```cs
Connection = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
Connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
```

and using the first one is a mistake - exceptions rised by are not captures by `EnsureDeleted()` method.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do to ensure this works.

1. You need to ensure your `ConnectionString` has `Persist Security Info=True`

```
Server=127.0.0.1,1433;Database=MyDatabase;User Id=sa;Password=........;TrustServerCertificate=True;Persist Security Info=True
```

2. You need to ensure you set the database back into `MULTI_USER` mode after creating/migrating the database.

```
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET MULTI_USER
```

Here is an example class.

```cs
private static int DbCreated;

private static void EnsureDatabaseIsCreated(IServiceProvider rootServiceProvider)
{
    int originalDbCreated = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref DbCreated, value: 1, comparand: 0);
    if (originalDbCreated == 0)
    {
        using var scope = rooterviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
        context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        context.Database.Migrate();
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET MULTI_USER;");
    }
}
```